# Asp.net mvc 5 C# how to loop through model list?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Here in my code, I am getting the day of the week into my model object than i parse it into Json but i would like to know if
is there a way to make this more simplier and more Effective?
Thanks for your answers!

```
    public JsonResult GetCalendarByParam(int year, string month, int date, string type, string operation)
    {
        DateWeekModels returnDate = new DateWeekModels();

        returnDate.Week = new List<Day>();

        Day dy1 = new Day();
        Day dy2 = new Day();
        Day dy3 = new Day();
        Day dy4 = new Day();
        Day dy5 = new Day();
        Day dy6 = new Day();
        Day dy7 = new Day();

        var monthReceive = DateTime.ParseExact(month, "MMMM", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture).Month;

        var dt = new DateTime(year, monthReceive, date);

        switch (type)
        {
            case "Month":
                if (operation == "+")
                {
                    dt = dt.AddMonths(1);
                }
                else
                {
                    dt = dt.AddMonths(-1);
                    if (DateTime.Compare(dt, DateTime.Now) < 0)
                    {
                        dt = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day);
                    }
                }
                break;
            case "Week":
                if (operation == "+")
                {
                    dt = dt.AddDays(7);
                }
                else
                {
                    dt = dt.AddDays(-7);
                    if (DateTime.Compare(dt, DateTime.Now) < 0)
                    {
                        dt = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day);
                    }
                }
                break;
        }


        dt.ToString("ddd", new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name));

        returnDate.Year = dt.Year;
        returnDate.Month = dt.ToString("MMMM", new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name));

        dy1.dayName = dt.ToString("ddd", new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name));
        dy1.dayNumber = dt.Day;
        dt = dt.AddDays(1);
        dy2.dayName = dt.ToString("ddd", new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name));
        dy2.dayNumber = dt.Day;
        dt = dt.AddDays(1);
        dy3.dayName = dt.ToString("ddd", new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name));
        dy3.dayNumber = dt.Day;
        dt = dt.AddDays(1);
        dy4.dayName = dt.ToString("ddd", new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name));
        dy4.dayNumber = dt.Day;
        dt = dt.AddDays(1);
        dy5.dayName = dt.ToString("ddd", new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name));
        dy5.dayNumber = dt.Day;
        dt = dt.AddDays(1);
        dy6.dayName = dt.ToString("ddd", new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name));
        dy6.dayNumber = dt.Day;
        dt = dt.AddDays(1);
        dy7.dayName = dt.ToString("ddd", new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name));
        dy7.dayNumber = dt.Day;
        returnDate.Week.Add(dy1);
        returnDate.Week.Add(dy2);
        returnDate.Week.Add(dy3);
        returnDate.Week.Add(dy4);
        returnDate.Week.Add(dy5);
        returnDate.Week.Add(dy6);
        returnDate.Week.Add(dy7);



        return Json(returnDate, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

then with jquery I send my object  to my id but i have to hardcode it too is there a way to pass my id to my object so i don't have to hardcode but simply loop it ? thank you!

```
    <script>
var previousMonth = document.getElementById("previousMonth");
previousMonth.addEventListener("click", function () { calendarManager("Month", "-") }, false);

var nextMonth = document.getElementById("nextMonth");
nextMonth.addEventListener("click", function () { calendarManager("Month", "+") }, false);

var nextWeek = document.getElementById("nextWeek");
nextWeek.addEventListener("click", function () { calendarManager("Week", "+") }, false);

var previousWeek = document.getElementById("previousWeek");
previousWeek.addEventListener("click", function () { calendarManager("Week", "-") }, false);

function calendarManager(type, operator) {
    var monthNow = $("#month").html();
    var yearNow = $("#year").html();
    var dayNow = $("#date1").html();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '@Url.Action("GetCalendarByParam", "Home")',
       dataType: "Json",
       data: {
           "year": yearNow,
           "month": monthNow,
           "date": dayNow,
           "type": type,
           "operation": operator
       },
       success: function (data) {
           $(".month").html(data.Month);
           $(".year").html(data.Year);
           var id;
           for (var i = 1, n = 0; i < 8;i++,n++){
               $("Day"  i).html(data.Week[n].dayName);
               //$("#date1").html(data.Week[0].dayNumber);
               //$("#day2").html(data.Week[1].dayName);
               //$("#date2").html(data.Week[1].dayNumber);
               //$("#day3").html(data.Week[2].dayName);
               //$("#date3").html(data.Week[2].dayNumber);
               //$("#day4").html(data.Week[3].dayName);
               //$("#date4").html(data.Week[3].dayNumber);
               //$("#day5").html(data.Week[4].dayName);
               //$("#date5").html(data.Week[4].dayNumber);
               //$("#day6").html(data.Week[5].dayName);
               //$("#date6").html(data.Week[5].dayNumber);
               //$("#day7").html(data.Week[6].dayName);
               //$("#date7").html(data.Week[6].dayNumber);
           }
           $(".tbDay1").attr("data-title", data.Week[0].dayName + " " + data.Week[0].dayNumber);
           $(".tbDay2").attr("data-title", data.Week[1].dayName + " " + data.Week[1].dayNumber);
           $(".tbDay3").attr("data-title", data.Week[2].dayName + " " + data.Week[2].dayNumber);
           $(".tbDay4").attr("data-title", data.Week[3].dayName + " " + data.Week[3].dayNumber);
           $(".tbDay5").attr("data-title", data.Week[4].dayName + " " + data.Week[4].dayNumber);
           $(".tbDay6").attr("data-title", data.Week[5].dayName + " " + data.Week[5].dayNumber);
           $(".tbDay7").attr("data-title", data.Week[6].dayName + " " + data.Week[6].dayNumber);
       },
   });
```

};

**UPDATE**

I was able to reduce my jquery code to this

```
   <script>
var previousMonth = document.getElementById("previousMonth");
previousMonth.addEventListener("click", function () { calendarManager("Month", "-") }, false);

var nextMonth = document.getElementById("nextMonth");
nextMonth.addEventListener("click", function () { calendarManager("Month", "+") }, false);

var nextWeek = document.getElementById("nextWeek");
nextWeek.addEventListener("click", function () { calendarManager("Week", "+") }, false);

var previousWeek = document.getElementById("previousWeek");
previousWeek.addEventListener("click", function () { calendarManager("Week", "-") }, false);

function calendarManager(type, operator) {
    var monthNow = $("#month").html();
    var yearNow = $("#year").html();
    var dayNow = $("#date1").html();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '@Url.Action("GetCalendarByParam", "Home")',
       dataType: "Json",
       data: {
           "year": yearNow,
           "month": monthNow,
           "date": dayNow,
           "type": type,
           "operation": operator
       },
       success: function (data) {
           $(".month").html(data.Month);
           $(".year").html(data.Year);
           var idDate, idDay,classTbDay;
           for (var i = 1, n = 0; i < 8; i++, n++) {
               idDate = "#date" + i;
               idDay = "#day" + i;
               classTbDay = ".tbDay" + i;
               console.log(idDate);
               $(idDate).html(data.Week[n].dayNumber);
               $(idDay).html(data.Week[n].dayName);
               $(classTbDay).attr("data-title", data.Week[n].dayName + " " + data.Week[n].dayNumber);
           }
       },
   });
```

};

Comment: what is it that you are trying to do?  What does "I am getting the day of the week into my model object" mean?  We have no idea what your "model" is or what it does.  At the very least, you can use an array and loops, rather than having 7 separate Day variables in your C# code.  Highly repetitive code like that should be a no-brainer to turn into a loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using loops, your c# code should reduce like this:

```
public JsonResult GetCalendarByParam(int year, string month, int date, string type, string operation)
{
    DateWeekModels returnDate = new DateWeekModels();

    returnDate.Week = new List<Day>();

    for (int i=0; i<7; i++) {
        returnDate.Week.Add(new Day());
    }

    var monthReceive = DateTime.ParseExact(month, "MMMM", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture).Month;
    var dt = new DateTime(year, monthReceive, date);

    switch (type)
    {
        case "Month":
            if (operation == "+")
            {
                dt = dt.AddMonths(1);
            }
            else
            {
                dt = dt.AddMonths(-1);
                if (DateTime.Compare(dt, DateTime.Now) < 0)
                {
                    dt = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day);
                }
            }
            break;
        case "Week":
            if (operation == "+")
            {
                dt = dt.AddDays(7);
            }
            else
            {
                dt = dt.AddDays(-7);
                if (DateTime.Compare(dt, DateTime.Now) < 0)
                {
                    dt = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day);
                }
            }
            break;
    }


    dt.ToString("ddd", new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name));

    returnDate.Year = dt.Year;
    returnDate.Month = dt.ToString("MMMM", new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name));

    foreach (Day thisDay in returnDate.Week)  {
        thisDay.dayName = dt.ToString("ddd", new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name));
        thisDay.dayNumber = dt.Day;
        dt = dt.AddDays(1);
    }

    return Json(returnDate, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```